# Rewrite and redirect in asp.net rewrite rules

Tags: c#, .net, url-rewriting

I am really struggling to understand rewrite rules and why mine do not do as id expect.

I have 2 rules, and basically what I need to achieve is that it picks up my pretty URL, regardless of sub directory and then redirect to a specific folder. This will then use an id, which is specified in the pretty URL to then hit the appropriate page in my solution.

So, this rule should be able to grab anything that comes before the pretty URL and then redirect to the folder /gen1/ from the root directory.

```
<rule name="PokemonGen1Rule 1">
    <match url="^gen1-[\w-]*[^?]*-pkmid([\d]+)\.html" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="^/gen1/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

This rule should then catch the url as it hits the gen1 folder and use the id contained within the pretty url, to pass it is as a parameter to the pokemon.aspx page.

```
<rule name="PokemonGen1Rule 2">
    <match url="^gen1/gen1-[\w-]*[^?]*-pkmid([\d]+)\.html" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/gen1/pokemon.aspx?pkmid={R:1}" 
    appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

It doesnt work, yet in my brain i cant work out whats broken. I've tried various different combinations of putting chevrons, and whatnot and it doesnt work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="PokemonGen1Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="[\w-]*[^?]*/(gen1-[\w-]*[^?]*-pkmid([\d]+)\.html)" 
    ignoreCase="true" />
       <conditions>
         <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" 
           pattern="/gen1/gen1-[\w-]*[^?]*-pkmid([\d]+)\.html" 
           ignoreCase="true" />
       </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="/gen1/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="PokemonGen1Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="[\w-]*[^?]*/gen1-[\w-]*[^?]*-pkmid([\d]+)\.html" 
    ignoreCase="true" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/gen1/pokemon.aspx?pkmid={R:1}" 
     appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Solved it!